# Energy velocity paradox

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, reference-frames, inertial-frames

I seems to be an paradox when working with energy. If a person going 20 m/s to 40 m/s the kinetical energy gain is (40^2-20^2)/2= 600 J.

Now imagine that i goinng in the opposite diraction with speed 10 m/s. Now the kinetical energy gain of the person is (50^2-30^2)/2=800 J.

I see this as an Paradox?

Maybe not, just an effect of two different moving reference frame...

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230054/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51220